# Area of a quadrilateral given lengths its sides and some angles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, pythagorean-triples

Given a quadrilateral with vertices $ABCD$ clockwisely, let $O$ be the midpoint of the line segment $AD$. Suppose $\angle AOB = \angle BOC = \angle COD = \pi/3$ and $AB = a, CD = b, BC = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, where $a, b$ are two positive real numbers. Compute the area of this quadrilateral in terms of $a$ and $b$.

I have tried to use the law of cosines to formulate 3 equations:

$$\begin{cases} 
x^2+y^2-xy = a^2, \\
x^2+z^2-xz = b^2, \\
y^2+z^2-yz = a^2+b^2,
\end{cases}$$
where $OA = OD = x$, $OB = y$, $OC = z$. Certainly I can solve these equations, however I would like to know if there is a nice geometric approach to obtain this area. Thanks!

Comment: *"Certainly I can solve these equations"* ... Please do. This will save people the trouble of doing that work if they want to, say, construct an accurate diagram for their geometric investigations. It will also help with sanity-checking answers.

Comment: @Blue I thought it could be done in Mathematica when I asked this question. But when I tried just now, it turns out that the resulting solution is quite involved and intractable. So if anyone could approach it algebraically, that would also be very helpful.

Comment: FYI: Using *Mathematica*'s `Resultant` function, I've found that $x$, $y$, $z$ are roots of these polynomials: $$\begin{align}
4x^8-2(a^2+b^2)x^6+(a^4+3a^2b^2+b^4)x^4\\[4pt]-2a^2b^2(a^2+b^2)x^2+a^4b^4 &=0\\[8pt] 4y^8-2(10a^2+b^2)y^6+(37a^4+3a^2b^2+b^4)y^4\\[4pt] -2a^2(15a^4-2a^2b^2+b^4)y^2+a^4(3a^2-b^2)^2 &=0\\[8pt] 4z^8-2(a^2+10b^2)z^6+(a^4+3a^2b^2+37b^4)z^4\\[4pt] -2b^2(a^4-2a^2b^2+15b^4)z^2+b^4(a^2-3b^2)^2 &=0
\end{align}$$ Given that these are effectively fourth-degree equations in $x^2$, $y^2$, $z^2$, I wouldn't be optimistic about a geometric solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case, you have an inverted equilateral triangle sided by two half-equilateral triangles making it a rectangle and $BC\ne\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Sides a and b are $\sqrt{1-(\frac {1}{2})^2}= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ times the sides of an equilateral triangle side which is also the width of the "rectangle". This means the top and botom are the inverse ratio times a or b. Assuming $a=b=1$, the area is $h\times w=1\times\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Making $BC=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ requires that they have lengths such as $3$ and $4$, respectively or $5,12$ or $7,24$ for an infinite number os solutions. (not true exactly) From here, assuming the left side where we have a triangle  with  sides $(a,\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$ and the right where we have a triangle with sides $(\sqrt{a^2+b^2},b)$, if we pulled these two together, the peak forms a right triangle having sides a and b. The bottom is the same as BC+ another BC and the altitude is the same as though there were two half-equilateral triangle beside the central inverted equilateral triangle.

This means the area is $$h\times width_{avg}=\frac{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}\cdot\frac{(2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{a^2+b^2})}{2}
=\frac{3\sqrt{3}(a^2+b^2)}{4}$$